# Can I block enemy's port if my navy is on the sea sector next to a factory zone?

Tags: axis-and-allies

**No House Rules**

So lets say I have a navy as the Japanese on the american port of western america.

Is that port now blocked? Or does America have to build its navy at the other factory or build a navy on that sea zone and go into instant battle?.

I don't see going into an instant battle being realistic to the game rules because that's not the attack phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer after reading the rule book for 17th time after awhile.

Clearly the rules state on page 20 paragraph 2 in section **restrictions on Placement**

"Place sea units only in sea zones adjacent to territories containing eligible industrial complexes. New sea units can enter play even in a hostile sea zone. No combat occurs because the Conduct Combat phase is over."

So yes build your navy in the hostile navy sea sector adjacent to your factory but no battle is committed.

Answer (score 1):

If you occupy the opponent's factory zone with a land or air unit, the opponent doesn't get to build on that zone. You do.

But the question was for the naval unit. It will be in an ocean zone *next to* the port zone, not in the port zone itself (it can't go on land).

The American player builds and deploys a new naval piece from the port zone to the adjacent Pacific zone side by side with the Japanese unit. This is the one time he does *not* attack, when there are opposing units in the same zone, because the "build" phase follows the combat phase. Put another way, the American unit ends its turn by "leaving port" as opposed to "attacking."

On the next move of the *Japanese* player, that player is deemed the attacker. He has the option of actually attacking (except with a transport), or of retreating the pieces in the hostile sea zone.